# Interconnecting Modules Aren't Connecting

Tags: verilog

I have a module Decode and a module RegisterBank. The decode passes an address to register, where it returns the data in a register. I've tried interconnecting these modules but I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly at this point. Any help would be much appreciated!

My Decode module:

```
module DecodeStage(  //Receives instruction and prepares the operands to be processed by ALU
input clk, 
//extract address, pass to register bank, receive back from register bank
input[31:0] InstrIn, //Extract operand register address from instruction 
output reg[3:0] address1_ds, //Pass to register bank
output reg[3:0] address2_ds, 
input[31:0] regval1_ds, //Receive values returned by the register bank
input[31:0] regval2_ds

);

wire [3:0] addr1; wire [3:0] addr2;
wire [31:0] outreg1;wire [31:0] outreg2;

//Connect Register Bank Module
RegisterBank register(
.rw_ds          (rw_ds),
.address1_ds    (addr1), //input[3:0]
.address2_ds    (addr2), //input[3:0]
.outval1_ds     (outreg1), //output reg[31:0]
.outval2_ds     (outreg2), //output reg[31:0]
);

//wire assigns
assign regval1_ds = outreg1;
assign regval2_ds = outreg2;
assign addr1 = address1_ds;
assign addr2 = address2_ds;


always @ (posedge clk)
begin   

    //Extract operand register address from instruction
    address1_ds = InstrIn[7:4];
    address2_ds = InstrIn[3:0];

end
endmodule
```

And here's my RegisterBank:

```
module RegisterBank(
input rw_ds, //boolean - 0 for read, 1 for write
input[3:0] address1_ds, //get address from decode
input[3:0] address2_ds, //get address from decode
output reg[31:0]outval1_ds, //output register data to decode
output reg[31:0]outval2_ds //output register data to decode
);

reg [31:0] register[0:15]; //array of sixteen 32 bit registers


always @ (posedge address1_ds, address2_ds, inval_ds, addr_wr_ds, inval_es, addr_wr_es) //WHAT SHOULD I MAKE THE ALWAYS TRIGGER ON
begin

    //declare what's in the registers
    register[0] = 0; register[1] = 1; register[2] = 2; register[3] = 3;
    register[4] = 4; register[5] = 5; register[6] = 6; register[7] = 7;
    register[8] = 8; register[9] = 9; register[10] = 10; register[11] = 11;
    register[12] = 12; register[13] = 13; register[14] = 14; register[15] = 15;

    //DECODE
    //If read, read values from registers
    if (rw_ds == 0)
    begin
        outval1_ds = register[address1_ds];
        outval2_ds = register[address2_ds];

    end

    //If write, write contents of address 1 to address 2
    if (rw_ds == 1)
    begin
        register[addr_wr_ds] = inval_ds;
    end


end

endmodule
```

Essentially, address1_ds gets sent via wire addr1 to Register. Register sends back outval1_ds, which is wire outreg1, input to Decode as regval1.

Answer (score 0):

```
RegisterBank register(
.rw_ds          (rw_ds),
.address1_ds    (addr1), //input[3:0]
.address2_ds    (addr2), //input[3:0]
.outval1_ds     (outreg1), //output reg[31:0]
.outval2_ds     (outreg2),//output reg[31:0]
);
```

**1)** Remove the extra comma after **outreg2** signal from the instantiation of **RegisterBank** module.

**2)** Variables **'addr_wr_es'** , **'inval_ds'** , **'addr_wr_ds'**, **'inval_es'** have not been declared in the **RegisterBank** module but used in the sensitivity list. The signal **rw_ds** in the module **DecodeStage** has not been declared but used. **Declare all the variables explicitly.**

Verilog-2001 added a new **`default_nettype** option, “**none**.” Specifying a **none** option tells the compiler that all the variables must be explicitly declared and that no default type is inferred. This was mainly introduced to remove any undeclared variables that could arise out of typos.

**Fixing these will help in compiling and simulating the code.**

Answer (score 0):

Remove this extra stuff too, connecting them is as good as assign

```
//wire assigns
assign regval1_ds = outreg1;
assign regval2_ds = outreg2;
assign addr1 = address1_ds;
assign addr2 = address2_ds;
```